# Capistrano aborta cuando ejecuta bundle install Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

Tengo un problema al hacer deploy sobre Ubuntu 16.04 en Digital Ocean, concretamente cuando ejecuto `$ cap production deploy --trace` se aborta el comando en la parte donde hace **bundle:install**, la última linea donde ya no pasa capistrano es esta: `$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deployer/RMG_rodeobest/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet` la cual ejecute en el servidor directamente, y me responde **Could not locate Gemfile** pero no entiendo por que pasa esto?

Agrego [aquí el log](http://pastebin.com/raw/gvfkserk)

Los links simbolicos de **deploy.rb**:

```
# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
# If you are using rbenv add these lines:
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
# require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

Alguna idea de que pueda estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hace bundle:install capistrano no puede encontrar Gemfile.

Probá varias cosas:

- revisá que git no esté excluyendo el archivo Gemfile del repositorio. De ser así no lo está copiando a tu droplet al momento de hacer el deploy
- probá de agregar el archivo Gemfile en los linked_files de deploy.rb
- último y peor caso de todos, copiá el archivo a mano